# Longest increasing subarray in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to come up with a solution for the next problem: Write a function in OCaml which has the first and the last index of the longest increasing subarray as an output. I am struggling with the error repairment.
So far, I have written this :

Example:

```
longest_increasing_subarray [|2;4;6;9;1;5;3;5;0;8;9;13;17|];;
- : (8,12)
```

This is my code so far:

```
let longest_increasing_subarray p1 =
  let n = Array.length p1
  and beg = ref 0
  and larg = ref(0,0) in
  for i=0 to n-1 do begin
    if i=0 then begin
    end;
    if p1.(i-1)<p1.(i) then
      begin
        if (snd !larg - fst !larg +1)<((i-1)-(!beg+1)) then
          !larg = (!beg,i-1)
            !beg = i end;
    if (i=n-1) then
      begin if (snd !larg-fst !larg +1)<((i)-(!beg)+1) then
          !larg := (!beg,i)
      end;
  end;
  done;
  !larg;;
```

Comment: I think you forgot to actually ask the question :)  Like are you trying to resolve the type errors in your code, or are you asking of what approach should be taken? Please, edit your post and add an explicit question, otherwise, it will be closed as "too broad".

Comment: Here are some [tips for asking good questions](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems with your code and your approach, let me highlight them in a Q&A form:

1. How to assign a value to a reference

   - Correct:

     ```
     x := v
     ```
   - Wrong:

     ```
     x = v
     !x = v
     !x := v
     ```
2. How to make two assignments in a row

   - Correct:

     ```
     x := v;
     y := p
     ```
   - Wrong:

     ```
     x := v
     y := p
     ```
3. How to branch on a condition

   - Correct:

     ```
     if p1.(i - 1) < p1.(i) 
     then update_indices i;
     else reset_indices ();
     ```
   - Wrong:

     ```
     if p1.(i - 1) < p1.(i) 
     then begin update_indices i end
     reset_indices ()
     ```
4. How to learn OCaml

   - Correct: read the [OCaml manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/coreexamples.html) and [other books](http://ocaml.org/learn/books.html)
   - Wrong: Post on SO hoping that someone will give you the codes
5. How to implement the `longest_increasing_subarray` function

   - Correct:

```
    Use a recursive function `find_longest` that will have four parameters:
       - `p` - the beginning of the longest sequence;
       - `q` - the end of the longest sequence; 
       - `s` - the beginning of the current working hypothesis
       - `t` - the end of the current working hypothesis;
       - `i` - the array index;
    The longest increasing sequence in the array `a` is defined as
    `find_longest 0 0 0 0 1`. The `find_longest` has the following definiton:
       - if `i >= Array.length a` then the result is 
          - `(p,q)` if `p - q > t - s` 
          - `(s,t)` otherwise
       - else if `a.(i-1) < a.(i)` then the result is `find_longest p q s i (i+1)`
       - else if `q - p < t - s` then the result is `find_longest s t i i (i+1)`
       - else the result is `find_longest p q i i (i+1)`
```

- Wrong: use imperative for-loops, references, etc